# $.getscript creates multiple calls when using swup library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getscript

For those unfamiliar, I am using a library called swup to create page transitions using CSS. Repo and info here: https://github.com/gmrchk/swup

This is essentially an alternative to ajax transitions that I felt was pretty interesting and easier for me to use on my portfolio site.

My issue is that I need to load my script file when new content is loaded via swup. I’m using jQuery currently to just load my script file. The $.getscript function is called using an event from swup, called 'swup:contentReplaced':

```
document.addEventListener('swup:contentReplaced', event => {
  $.getScript("/js/main.js");
});
```

The problem with this is that this creates some sort of error that doubles every call created by swup. So the next time the 'swup:contentReplaced' event occurs, the main.js file is called twice. Then 4 times. Then 8, and so on.

This of course destroys performance and pretty much makes the computer freeze. What is a better way of calling that js file when content is loaded via swup on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your `main.js` change the content and thus re-advocate the event twice.

One option is, add global field in html which is flagged as `false`, and dig into your `main.js` find the piece of code cause you trouble like,

```
//In HTML
<data style="display:none" id="flag" value="0" />

//In main.js
$('#flag').val("1");
//...Part causes trouble
$('#flag').val("0");

//eventListener
document.addEventListener('swup:contentReplaced', event => {
  if $('#flag').val() == "0"{
     $.getScript("/js/main.js");
  }
});
```

---

But that may not solve the problem as you may find some trouble of locating the problematic part (lets say).

Then, a more convenient way is using `once`

```
document.addEventListener('swup:contentReplaced', event => {
  $.getScript("/js/main.js");
}, {once:true});
```

and **at the end of `main.js`, also add this line**.

And thus everytime you can only call the `$.getScript("/js/main.js");` for one time, and just after you execute the `main.js`, you add back the event.